# The requested resource was not found on this server. Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, http-status-code-404

I've a very wired situatio. When I run the Login.php from Netbeans it loads fine on the browser page, but after I entered the required info and press enter, the page refreshes and shows me the following 404 Not Found error:

> The requested resource /Student/Login.php was not found on this
>   server.

Notes:

- the Login.php is the first page to run in my project.
- Login.php which I run is in the root directory (not inside Student folder).
- I don't have another Login.php file inside Student folder.

The browser keeps looking for Login.php file inside the Student folder rather than in the root directory.

Please advice!

Comment: Show us the form and any other relevant code.

Comment: You should also read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you sure it is related to netbeans ?